# Ending the multiprocessing queue

Tags: python, asynchronous, process, queue, shared-memory

I want to have the following code run while the cycle for places the items in a queue for the processes to get and print. While the father process is creating the items, the child process writes them.

```
MAX_SIZE = 5

full = Semaphore(0)
empty = Semaphore(1)

testQueue = Queue()

valueLock = Lock()

processList = []


def prodt():
    for i in range(101):
        empty.acquire()
        testQueue.put(i)
        full.release()

def cons():
    while True: #I need a condition for exiting the process when the cycle in prod() ends and puts 
                #all of the items in the queue
        full.acquire()
        idx = testQueue.get()
        empty.release()
        print(idx)

for i in range(2):
    processList.append(Process(target=cons))

for i in processList:
    i.start()

prodt()

for i in processList:
    i.join()
```

But the program gets stuck when all of the items in the queue are processed

Comment: "the father process" - amazing naming )

Comment: 1) you don't need that Semafors in your case; 2) why are you consuming the queue before you added any items to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a discrete process that's consuming data from a queue, you have to have some mechanism to inform that process that it should terminate.

One way to do this is to put a value of None on the queue.

Here's an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from itertools import repeat

NPROCS = 2 # number of consumers

def producer(q, n):
    # put a range of values on the queue
    for i in range(1_000):
        q.put(i)
    # the value n passed to this process indicates the number of consumer processes
    # each consumer instance needs to see None in order to terminate properly
    for _ in range(n):
        q.put(None)

def consumer(q):
    # consume values from the queue printing them out until None
    # is observed then terminate
    while (v := q.get()) is not None:
        print(v)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        q = manager.Queue()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=NPROCS+1) as ppe:
            ppe.submit(producer, q, NPROCS)
            ppe.map(consumer, repeat(q, NPROCS))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```